# Livet で確認ダイアログのデフォルトフォーカスを Cancel にしたい。

Tags: wpf, xaml

Livet WPF4.5 を使っています。

`ConfirmationDialogInteractionMessageAction` で `OKCancel` ダイアログを出すとデフォルトのフォーカスが OK になるのですがこれを Cancel にすることはできるのでしょうか？

```
<l:ConfirmationDialogInteractionMessageAction>
  <l:DirectInteractionMessage CallbackCommand="{Binding ClearCommand}">
    <l:ConfirmationMessage Button="OKCancel"
                           Caption="確認"
                           Text="本当に全消去しますか？"
                           Image="Information" />
  </l:DirectInteractionMessage>
</l:ConfirmationDialogInteractionMessageAction>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

標準の機能では出来ないはずです。

`ConfirmationMessage`を継承してデフォルトフォーカス用のプロパティを増やし、
`ConfirmationDialogInteractionMessageAction`を参考に新しい`InteractionMessageAction<FrameworkElement>`を継承した`TriggerAction`を作ることで実現できます。

実装例としては以下のような形になるかと。

```
public class FocusableConfirmationMessage : ConfirmationMessage
{
    public MessageBoxResult DefaultFocus
    {
        get { return (MessageBoxResult)GetValue(DefaultFocusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DefaultFocusProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DefaultFocus.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultFocus", typeof(MessageBoxResult), typeof(FocusableConfirmationMessage), new PropertyMetadata(MessageBoxResult.None));

    public FocusableConfirmationMessage() : base()
    {

    }

    public FocusableConfirmationMessage(string text, string caption, MessageBoxImage image, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxResult defaultFocus, string messageKey)
        : base(text,caption,image,button,messageKey)
    {
        this.DefaultFocus = defaultFocus;
    }
}

public class FocusableConfirmationDialogInteractionMessageAction : InteractionMessageAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void InvokeAction(InteractionMessage message)
    {
        var confirmMessage = message as FocusableConfirmationMessage;
        if (confirmMessage != null)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show(
                confirmMessage.Text,
                confirmMessage.Caption,
                confirmMessage.Button,
                confirmMessage.Image,
                confirmMessage.DefaultFocus
                );

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes || result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                confirmMessage.Response = true;
            }
            else if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                confirmMessage.Response = null;
            }
            else
            {
                confirmMessage.Response = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FocusableConfirmationMessage`に`CreateInstanceCore`を実装しておくとコードからも呼び出せるようになりますね。
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
      return new FocusableConfirmationMessage();
    }